# Save Debian automaticaly

Tags: save, debian, directory, automatic-storage

I have a Debian server and I wish to "save" some files automatically and send them automatically to a googledrive. this automatic task must be done regularly (every week, for example)

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of a weird question, there is a lot of good backup tools.

But if you **really want to use Google Drive** weekly, you can use [this tutorial](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29279/Backup-Linux-Servers-to-Google-Drive.html).

Then you'll have to put a [crontab](https://crontab.guru/every-week) :

```
crontab -e
0 0 * * 0
```